# Unreal Engine 4 C++: Unable to assign subclass instance to a TSubclassOf variable

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

As stated in the title, I'm currently working in C++ on a project of mine and Im unable to assign an instance of a class to a variable in another class that is expecting a subclass of the instances parent class.

In more detail I have 3 classes right now: USpell, UProjectilePrimarySpell, and UPreparedSpell.

UProjectilePrimarySpell inherits from USpell which is an abstract class.

```
UCLASS(Abstract)
class SPELLCRAFTER_API USpell : public UObject
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:

    USpell();

    USpell(FString element);

    UPROPERTY()
    FString element;

    UFUNCTION()
    virtual void castSpell(FVector targetPoint, FRotator targetRotation);

    UFUNCTION()
    virtual void weaveSpell();
};

UCLASS()
class SPELLCRAFTER_API UProjectilePrimarySpell : public USpell
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

    UPROPERTY()
    float projectileSpeed;

    UPROPERTY()
    float projectileScale;

    UPROPERTY()
    bool isBurst;

    UPROPERTY()
    int32 burstCount;

    UPROPERTY()
    float burstDelay;

    UPROPERTY()
    bool isShotgun;

    UPROPERTY()
    int32 shotgunPelletCount;

    UPROPERTY()
    float castDelay;

    UPROPERTY()
    float cooldown;

    UPROPERTY()
    float despawnTime;

    UPROPERTY()
    int32 damage;

    UPROPERTY()
    bool isAffectedByGravity;

public:

    UProjectilePrimarySpell();

    void castSpell(FVector targetLocation, FRotator targetRotation);
};
```

UPreparedSpell has a field called PrimarySpell which is of type TSubclassOf;

```
UCLASS()
class SPELLCRAFTER_API UPreparedSpell : public UObject
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:

    UPreparedSpell();

    UPreparedSpell(TSubclassOf<USpell> primarySpell);

    UPreparedSpell(TSubclassOf<USpell> primarySpell, TArray<TSubclassOf<USpell>> secondarySpells);

    UPROPERTY()
    TSubclassOf<USpell> PrimarySpell;

    UPROPERTY()
    TArray<TSubclassOf<USpell>> SecondarySpells;

    UFUNCTION()
    void CastPreparedSpell(FVector targetPoint, FRotator targetRotation);
};
```

In a separate class which I have some code running when the player performs some input. In there I am creating an instance of the UProjectilePrimarySpell class and an instance of the UPreparedSpell both using the NewObject function.

I then attempt to assign the UProjectilePrimarySpell instance to the field in the UPreparedSpell however I'm getting an error saying

*no operator "=" matches these operands. Operand types are TSubclassOf = UProjectilePrimarySpell*

Where I assign PrimarySpell to *baseSpell;

```
void ASpellcrafterCharacter::OnFire()
{

    const FRotator SpawnRotation = GetControlRotation();
    // MuzzleOffset is in camera space, so transform it to world space before offsetting from the character location to find the final muzzle position
    const FVector SpawnLocation = ((FP_MuzzleLocation != nullptr) ? FP_MuzzleLocation->GetComponentLocation() : GetActorLocation()) + SpawnRotation.RotateVector(GunOffset);

    UProjectilePrimarySpell *baseSpell = NewObject<UProjectilePrimarySpell>();

    UPreparedSpell* preparedSpell = NewObject<UPreparedSpell>();

    preparedSpell->PrimarySpell = *baseSpell;
    preparedSpells.Add(preparedSpell);

    preparedSpells[0]->CastPreparedSpell(SpawnLocation, SpawnRotation);

}
```

I'm fairly greenhorn when it comes to C++ and Unreal engine, I understand the basics of pointers and I've got years of experience in Java so I understand how inheritance should work. I'm confused as to why this isnt a valid setup.

Comment: A class is different from an instance. In unreal terms a class is type associated with a particular set of instances. I.e. your game may have many instanced bullets but there's only ever one bullet class. There's one unreal class per UCLASS in code and blueprint in data. If you're really trying to store an instance of `preparedSpell` then use a pointer instead (and don't forget to initialise it to `nullptr`). Also, `preparedSpells[0]` probably won't do what you're expecting since `Add` adds an element to the back of a `TArray`.

Answer (score 2):

`TSubclassOf<>` is a templated type that can be thought of as simply a `UClass*`.

Variables of this type are meant to be assigned an *instance of a UClass*, to denote *different types of objects*. For example, if you have child classes of `USpell` called `UFireSpell` and `UHealSpell`, and let’s say they can be equipped to a slot on a weapon, you can use a `TSubclassOf<USpell> EquippedSpell` variable, and assign the slot to use heal spells (*not a specific heal spell*, but in general *the type of spell* used for healing) by doing something like `EquippedSpell = UHealSpell::Static_Class()`.

I hope this makes it clear that an *instance of a `UClass`* is different from an *instance of a `UObject`*, which is what you’re doing by creating a new object. If you create some objects of C++ class `UPreparedSpell`, they are `UPreparedSpell*` type. Their `UClass` (different from C++ class) can be found by using their `GetClass()` function, which  returns a pointer to `UClass`.

`preparedSpell->PrimarySpell = *baseSpell` doesn’t make sense, as you should never dereference a `UObject*`, they are non copyable.

For most Unreal programming, it’s quite important to understand what a `UClass` is. It’s not really the same as a C++ class, but rather a prototype, similar to what JavaScript objects use, if you’re familiar with that. If you’re not familiar with the term, search for “prototype based object oriented programming” if you want to learn more.